# How to concatenate two properties of object in array to use as label in ngOptions

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to concatenate two properties of object in array to use as label in ngOptions of angular JS? I have tried the below code, but get an error in the console.

```
<select name=artArtist class=form-control ng-model=artArtist ng-options="art.firstName + ' ' + art.lastName for art in artists" required></select>
```

The following code works, but produces the artist name without space between the first name and last name. What am I doing wrong?

```
<select name=artArtist class=form-control ng-model=artArtist ng-options="art.firstName + art.lastName for art in artists" required></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

`<select name="artArtist" class="form-control" ng-model="artArtist" ng-options="(art.firstName + '&nbsp;' + art.lastName) for art in artists" required></select>`

Comment: Doesn't work. Get this error SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list. Same as before

Comment: Still the same error. I am using uglify if that help

Answer (score 0):

Please, check your controller code.
I tried the following and works without errors.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">    
  <select name=artArtist class=form-control ng-model=artArtist ng-options="art.firstName + ' ' + art.lastName for art in artists" required></select>
</div>


function MyCtrl($scope) {

   $scope.artists = [{firstName: 'Mike',  lastName:'Random'},
                     {firstName: 'Lulu',  lastName:'Byte'},
                     {firstName: 'Sonia', lastName:'Link'}];

}
```

Try here
http://jsfiddle.net/1hempsf4/

Otherwise post your error.